# How to switch passed value through C++ standard type trait?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

I want to switch passed value through C++ standard type trait. Here is the test code show what I mean:

```
template<typename T>
T _func(T t, std::is_integral<T>||std::is_enum<T>)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T _func(T t, std::is_floating_point<T>)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T _func(T t, std::is_same<T, std::string>)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T func(T t)
{
    return _func(t, T)
}
```

It doesn't work of course. I try my best to test and find a way to implement this:

```
int testint(int t){ return t;}
std::string testString(std::string t ){return t;}
float testreal(float t ){return t;}

template <typename T>
T test_string_type(T t, std::true_type) {
    return testString(t);
}

template <typename T>
T test_string_type(T t, std::false_type) {
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T test_real_type(T t, std::true_type)
{
    return testreal(t) ;
}

template<typename T>
T test_real_type(T t, std::false_type)
{
    return test_string_type(t, std::is_same<T, std::string>());
}

template<typename T>
T test_enum_type(T t, std::true_type)
{
    return testint(t) ;
}

template<typename T>
T test_enum_type(T t, std::false_type)
{
    return test_real_type(t, std::is_floating_point<T>());
}

template<typename T>
T test_integer_type(T t, std::true_type)
{
    return testint(t) ;
}

template<typename T>
T test_integer_type(T t, std::false_type)
{
    return test_enum_type(t, std::is_enum<T>()) ;
}

template<typename T>
T test(T t)
{
    return test_integer_type(t, std::is_integral<T>());
}
```

It works, but really ugly code.
Is there any kind of smart way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to reject overloads

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>::type
 func(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type
 func(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value>::type 
 func(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

or use tag dispatching similar to what you've shown, but handle the alternatives differently to reduce the number of cases

```
namespace detail
{
template<typename T>
T func(T t, std::false_type /*is_string*/, std::false_type /*is_float*/, std::true_type /*is_int*/)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T func(T t, std::false_type /*is_string*/, std::true_type /*is_float*/, std::false_type /*is_int*/)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
T func(T t, std::true_type /*is_string*/, std::false_type /*is_float*/, std::false_type /*is_int*/)
{
    return t;
}
}

template<typename T>
T func(T t)
{
    return detail::func(t, std::is_same<string, T>(),
                           std::is_floating_point<T>(),
                           std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>());
}
```

Comment: That's really great!

Comment: And how to accept overloads for all other types?
template<typename T>
T func(T t)
{
    return t;
}
It does not work.

Comment: @Ringo_D For the tag dispatching example, add a `T func(T t, std::false_type, std::false_type, std::false_type)` overload. For the `enable_if` example, you'll need to form a boolean condition that is true only when none of the other traits above are true.

Comment: For the `enable_if` example, I should write a condition `!(std::is_integral || std:: is_enum || std::is_floating_point ...)`, right? It's ugly too.

Comment: @Ringo_D Yes, solutions involving `enable_if` are rarely pretty

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, in C++17 you can use [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
template <typename T>
T func(T t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value) {
        return t + 1;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
        return t + 2.5;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
        return t + " suffix";
    }

    return t;
}
```

This code compiles in Clang 3.9 and GCC 7.

Comment: I'm using C++11 now. But it's an amazing feature what I look forward to.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with SFINAE like so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct One {};
struct Two {};
struct Three {};

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value
                || std::is_enum<T>::value>* = nullptr>
One _func(T)
{
    return One{};
}

template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>* = nullptr>
Two _func(T)
{
    return Two{};
}

template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<
            std::decay_t<T>, std::string>::value>* = nullptr>
Three _func(T)
{
    return Three{};
}

template<typename T>
auto func(T t)
{
    return _func(t);
}

template <typename...>
struct WhichType;

int main() {
    WhichType<decltype(func(1))>{};
    WhichType<decltype(func(1.0))>{};
    WhichType<decltype(func(std::string{}))>{};
    return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of things to understand here, the first is SFINAE and how that works, but answering that will make this answer way too long and I will probably do a worse job than others,  so here is a reference to `std::enable_if` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and here is a reference to SFINAE (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/)

The other important thing to note here is the `std::decay_t` in one of the function templates.  If the passed in type is a `const string&` then the code will not be correct anymore as `std::is_same<const string&, std::string>::value` is false.  The `std::decay_t` removes all references, const qualifiers and volatile qualifiers.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay

The `WhichType` template is a technique used to inspect the type of a variable as described by Scott Meyers in the book Effective Modern C++.  Most compilers will output an error showing the type of the thing in the template.  Therefore it's useful when you want to know the type of an expression.  In this case it will output the return type of the function allowing you to see which function was called.

Comment: It does not work. The error is "Call to '_func' is ambiguous".

Comment: @Ringo_D fixed.  maybe thats why this wasnt getting any upvotes :(